# Which lines of "In the mood for love" are in Shanghainese, and which are in Chinese?

Tags: dialogue, in-the-mood-for-love

In the movie [*In the mood for love*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118694/) the characters speak Shanghainese and Cantonese. There are also songs in several languages, but this is easier to research.

I might be mistaken, but so far I get that Mrs. Suen (Rebecca Pan) speaks in Shanghainese to her daughter, who appears to understand correctly, but answers in Cantonese anyway.

What other characters/passages are in Shanghainese? What parts are in Cantonese? How can I know exactly which is which? Both sound Chinese to me (silly pun, I know).

Comment: This question actually sounds like the answer might "add to the understanding or appreciation of a movie": using different dialects/languages in social interactions can have an important emotional or symbolic function.

Comment: @Joachim: Indeed, miscommunication and being out of place are central to the movie. The director, Kar-Wai Wong, also seems to carefully craft his characters, so I believe this matters.